# Promote the application to test environment after successful build using Jenkins

Tags: deployment, jenkins

I am able to promote the application to test environment by running particular shell script. I want to automate this task using Jenkins. Where do i specify that shell script in Jenkins so that script is executed as soon as build is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins has plug-ins that will allow you to run shell scripts. The wiki pages for the plug-in typically shows you how to utilize them from within Jenkins. Here are two plug-ins that will run your shell script.

[Post Build Task](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Post+build+task)

[Managed Script Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Managed+Script+Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as a part of post build step.

[Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) can help you promote your builds to multiple environments. There are multiple such plugins depending on your needs.